# Element 3d placeholder to premiere pro?

Tags: after-effects, 3d, premiere-pro

Using a virtual studio package that uses Element 3D v2 with 2 Display screens meant for footage to be added. How can I render the scene which is heavy in after effects and leaving the Screen placeholders empty so that I can easily change the footage in Premiere Pro, not having to render the scene each timein AE? Any good tutorials or advice would be really helpful. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the question, sorry, but could you render out an AVI (both RGB + Alpha channels) of the scene (presuming that the areas for the video don't have anything behind them) from AE and then, in PPro, drop the AVI on a video layer above the videos, adjusting their size/scale to fit into the 'windows'?

In AE; if the video 'windows' aren't already cut out, you should be able to use a mask to get rid of them (you might need to pre-compose the layers if they're not in a comp already).